# How to store data in external drive with Docker Postgres:9.3 image?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, docker, devops

I want to setup my database inside a container using the Postgres:9.3 docker image, however I want to store my data in external drive.

I attempted it using the command

```
`docker run -dit -p 5432:5432 -v /mnt/external/docker_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data --name mydatabase postgres:9.3`
```

Container got created as it echoes the container id, but it is not shown as running from `docker ps`. The above command works for other images. So my gut feeling is that there is a conflict as this images has VOLUME defined in its dockerfile but I haven't figure out a way to get around it. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the problem is my /mnt/external/docker_volume was not empty and the Postgres init script didn't like it. I found this out after running with -it option and see the output in terminal.

I answered my own question. I hope somebody in the future will find this helpful. :)